# babel compiler with cucumber.js version 4

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cucumberjs

with cucumber@1, I could run tests that needed transpiling like this

```
cucumberjs --compiler js:babel-core/register
```

but that doesn't work with cucumber@4

```
node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --help
```

doesn't list the `--compiler` option anymore

it doesn't complain when I put the option in, but when it gets to the first jsx angle bracket, it complains.

Answer (score 3):

When you run `node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --help` you can see that the option to require a node module before requiring files is `--require-module` so an example would be `./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js --require-module @babel/register test/features`